# Scrapy request+response+download time

Tags: scrapy

**UPD**: Not close question because I think my way is not so clear as should be

Is it possible to get current request + response + download time for saving it to Item?

In "plain" python I do

```
start_time = time()
urllib2.urlopen('http://example.com').read()
time() - start_time
```

But how i can do this with Scrapy?

**UPD**:

Solution enought for me but I'm not sure of quality of results. If you have many connections with timeout errors `Download time` may be wrong (even DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT * 3)

For

settings.py

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myscraper.middlewares.DownloadTimer': 0,
}
```

middlewares.py

```
from time import time
from scrapy.http import Response


class DownloadTimer(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['__start_time'] = time()
        # this not block middlewares which are has greater number then this
        return None

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        request.meta['__end_time'] = time()
        return response  # return response coz we should

    def process_exception(self, request, exception, spider):
        request.meta['__end_time'] = time()
        return Response(
            url=request.url,
            status=110,
            request=request)
```

inside spider.py in `def parse(...`

```
log.msg('Download time: %.2f - %.2f = %.2f' % (
    response.meta['__end_time'], response.meta['__start_time'],
    response.meta['__end_time'] - response.meta['__start_time']
), level=log.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you need a Middleware here. Scrapy has a request.meta which you can query and yield. For download latency, simply yield

```
download_latency=response.meta.get('download_latency'),
```

> The amount of time spent to fetch the response, since the request has
>   been started, i.e. HTTP message sent over the network. This meta key
>   only becomes available when the response has been downloaded. While
>   most other meta keys are used to control Scrapy behavior, this one is
>   supposed to be read-only.

Answer (score 7):

You could write a [Downloader Middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) which would time each request. It would add a start time to the request before it's made and then a finish time when it's finished. Typically, arbitrary data such as this is stored in the [Request.meta](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta) attribute. This timing information could later be read by your spider and added to your item.

This downloader middleware sounds like it could be useful on many projects.

Comment: But considering that the requests are scheduled async, the requests can be processed by the downloader middleware possibly several seconds before they are actually initiated. Unless I'm missing something, this approach using the downloader middleware doesn't really work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is by using scrapy signals. Whenever the request reaches the downloader it emits *request_reached_downloader* signal. After download it emits *response_downloaded* signal. You can catch it from the spider and assign time and its differences to meta from there.

```
@classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler, *args, **kwargs):
        spider = super(SignalSpider, cls).from_crawler(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.item_scraped, signal=signals.item_scraped)
        return spider
```

More elaborate answer is on [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/signals.html#signals)