# Scrapy - Timing to get a Response

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Just like in [Scrapy request+response+download time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15831955/scrapy-requestresponsedownload-time), I would like to know how many time it takes to get a Response. The solution proposed doesn't meet my needs because of the following issue:

When a Downloader Middleware *process_request* method returns a Request object, the Request is rescheduled and isn't passed immediately to the remaining *process_request* methods. As a consequence, the solution proposed will include the time needed for the scheduler to return the Request to the Engine again.

What I want is only the time the Downloader takes to download a page (the time elapsed between the end of Downloader Middleware processings of the Request and first Downloader Middleware processing of the Response).

My idea is that one could either:

1. Disable the rescheduling of returned Request. But is it desirable and how can we do this?
2. Or Try to use the 'timer' used to trigger a TimeoutError. But I don't know how to access it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "the Request is rescheduled and isn't passed immediately to the remaining..." when is it rescheduled?

Comment: As stated in the [doc](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) of the process_request method: _If it returns a Request object, Scrapy will stop calling process_request methods and reschedule the returned request. Once the newly returned request is performed, the appropriate middleware chain will be called on the downloaded response._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this exactly what [`download_latency`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#download-latency) request `meta` key contains? Or your requirement is different?

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was searching for. However, I don't know the unit of time associated with the value obtained. I've searched what script set this meta in the Response object, but I can't find it. Do you know how this value is set?

Comment: Take a look at the [code](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/dc4b36a89ea647e9940db44bfe31c6a212d3cb01/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py#L322). Both start and end time are calls to [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time), so the `download_latency` should be in seconds.